# Regex extract full capture group

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'm trying to extract URLs but I am only getting the last portion like the "com" and not the full "amazon.com" or "google.com". I'm using the following regex:

```
data = [['website is amazon.com'], ['url is google.com']] 
reviews = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ALL_TEXT']) 
reviews['regex_match'] = reviews['ALL_TEXT'].str.extract(r'[^@A-Z][-A-Z0-9:%_\+~#=]+\.(CO|COM|NET|ORG|GOV)\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

I tried to use a capture group around the full regex

```
reviews['regex_match'] = reviews['ALL_TEXT'].str.extract(r'([^@A-Z][-A-Z0-9:%_\+~#=]+\.(CO|COM|NET|ORG|GOV)\b)', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

but I get the error

```
Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are assigning the result of `Series.str.extract` into a single column (`reviews['regex_match']`), but your regex contains *two* capturing groups, i.e. you tell it to return two columns.

You can use

```py
>>> reviews['ALL_TEXT'].str.extract(r'(?<![@A-Z])([-A-Z0-9:%_+~#=]+\.(?:COM?|NET|ORG|GOV))\b', flags=re.I)
            0
0  amazon.com
1  google.com
```

*Details*:

- `(?<![@A-Z])` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is a `@` or an ASCII letter immediately to the left of the current location
- `([-A-Z0-9:%_+~#=]+\.(?:COM?|NET|ORG|GOV))` - Capturing group 1 (this will be returned by `Series.str.extract`):

  - `[-A-Z0-9:%_+~#=]+` - one or more ASCII letters/digits, `-`, `:`, `%`, `_`, `+`, `~`, `#` or `=` chars
  - `\.` - a `.` char
  - `(?:COM?|NET|ORG|GOV)` - a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-in-regular-expressions) matching `co`, `com`, `net`, `org` or `gov`
- `\b` - a word boundary.

So, you only use a *single capturing group* to return the value for the single column you define to the left of the `=` operator, and if you need to group any two or more patterns, you just use *non-capturing* groups.

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because you are passing 2 capture groups. You can use a non capture group using `(?:` for the extensions and use a single capture group for the full pattern.

```
([^@A-Z][-A-Z0-9:%_+~#=]+\.(?:COM?|NET|ORG|GOV))\b
                           |__________________|
                             Non capture group
|______________________________________________|
                  Capture group
```

The updated code could look like

```
reviews['regex_match'] = reviews['ALL_TEXT'].str.extract(
    r'([^@A-Z][-A-Z0-9:%_+~#=]+\.(?:COM?|NET|ORG|GOV))\b',
    flags=re.IGNORECASE
)
```

Output

```
                ALL_TEXT  regex_match
0  website is amazon.com   amazon.com
1      url is google.com   google.com
```